# Change in precision due to use of inline function in C++ std::vector with g++ 4.4.7 20120313 in 32 bit

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I am compiling on centos5.9 32 bit (running on a 64 bit machine), targeting 32 bits. g++ version is 4.4.7, which is not the one shipped by default on centos5.9, but it can be downloaded with yum and is provided as part of the distro.

I have a very simple loop as follows

```
std::vector<double> result(n);
std::vector<double> values(n);
// here I compute values(). They are correct and I extensively noted 
// that there's nothing wrong there. The problem is here
result[0] = 0.0;
for ( int i = 0 ; i < n-1 ; ++i ) {
    result[i+1] = result[i]+values[i];
    // printf("x");
}
```

In a more complicated version of this code (which shows the exact same problem) I used the following operator for a class RealVector encapsulating a std::vector as a passthrough

```
inline double & operator[] (int index) { return data_[index]; }
```

The problem is that I found a tiny but relevant numerical difference in the result, depending if the operator[] is inline or not. 
Similarly, I also change the result if I uncomment the printf() line given above.
Note that the problem does not occur in a centos59 64 bit with the same configuration, or if it occurs, it's below detectability.

Is it a compiler bug, or there's some subtle magic going on? I tried to check both the asm and the parse tree, but it's too complex to understand. I generally manage with C, but in C++ there's too much dark magic going on in the resulting files.

Comment: Just an unrelated side-note: If you define a member function completely inside a class, like your operator seems to be, then it's implicitly defined `inline`. No need for the `inline` keyword there.

Comment: Joachim: good point, but I need to follow our coding standards.

Comment: @StefanoBorini: Then I advise to get them updated :) Asking for boilerplate seems a little weird...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably the old x87 fun feature again, 80 bits registers. Spilling that register to memory causes a rounding to 64 bits, and happens at unpredictable moments. Not at all unique to C++, C has the same issue. In Java it's "complicated"

Fixed by moving to 64 bit builds and SSE.

Comment: ...And in C# you just don't have a choice!  I had fun with this one for an afternoon once...

Comment: Interesting. Do you have some link so I can read further on this issue?